# How to make Maven Surefire log out where it is currently looking for tests?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm getting the below log from Maven Surefire when I can't properly find my path. Is there a way to make it spit out the directory in which `testSourceDirectory` is set?

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ project ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.549 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-02T19:31:08-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My pom.xml

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.22.0</version>
   <configuration />
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

My source code is in `src/main/java/org/company/project`.

My tests are in `src/test/java/org/company/project`

Tutorial I used to set up the pom.xml: https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/09/09/junit-5-maven-example/

I can run tests successfully with this pom.xml in this project: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.2.0/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven. But when I transfer that into my own project, it fails to pick up any specs.

Edit:
Apparently we were using `spring-boot-starter-test`, which only uses JUnit 4. Using https://info.michael-simons.eu/2018/06/18/maven-use-junit-5-with-spring-boot-for-unit-and-integration-tests/ to see if I can use JUnit 5.

Comment: by default it is `src/test/java` https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html where are your  tests?

Comment: Mine are in there, but nested down more. `src/test/java/org/my-project/`. I've added them to `testSourceDirectory` under `configuration` in pom.xml already, no luck. I've also tried playing with `testClassesDirectory`

Comment: add the rest of your POM. Maven is opinionated you do not need to configure it unless you go outside of the norms e.g. if your tests did not fall under `src/test/java`

Comment: I added it. Note, that the test files themselves are divided by different sub folders as well.

Comment: Have you named the tests accordingly to the naming conventions ? And remove the dependency to maven-surefire-plugin cause the referenced tutorial is simply outdated...See the docs of the maven-surefire-plugin: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html also the part for JUnit 5...

Comment: Did all those above, I even cloned and ran this: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.2.0/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven. Then tried to copy their pom.xml, no luck

Answer (score 1):

When running your tests try adding the -X parameter to maven

```
mvn -X test
```

and look for the parameter you're asking about. On my environment its value is

```
[DEBUG]   (s) testSourceDirectory = C:\Users\ME\MyWork\workspace\MyProject\src\test\java
```

Hope this helps.